# Cox Proportional Hazards- Calculate time at risk

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

Can you calculate the **time at set risk** from proportional hazard models in R?

Say I've got my model built for the whole population. The risk of developing an event in one year is 5%. After stratification, some patients have a higher risk, some lower.

How do I get a value, per patient, that will tell me **the time at which they have a 5% risk of developing an event**?

Apologies for not showing any code examples, I'm wondering if this is even possible. if it isn't, could you suggest other models?